# Print 'x' words after and before matched word using awk

Tags: regex, awk

I am searching for a particular word in a text file. The below command is returning every occurrence in that text file

```
awk '/text_to_be_searched/ { match($0, /text_to_be_searched/); print ( NR-1"-----"$0) ;}' filename.txt
```

But now I have to display only 'x' number of words before and after the matched word for the first occurrence.

Comment: How do you define a "word"? Any sequence of non-space chars separated by white space? Only contiguous alphabetic characters? Something else? Edit your question to include some sample input and expected output, especially cases that you think it'll be hard for a script to handle correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use grep instead

```
grep -Eo -m 1 '.{x}pattern.{y}' pattern files
```

x is the no of words to match before pattern

y is the no of words to match after pattern

`-m 1` means return the first match

*Note: any regex special characters in pattern should be escaped or else it would be interpreted as regex*

Comment: thanks  @Anirudha . is that x is no of lines ? . I am looking for no of words.

Comment: tried your solution but its moving from the actual result . Say for example , I have a word named 'test' in file and which is on the first line of file and no other words in that line. That time if command has 50 words(ie y value )  then it is searching for the next line which has pattern with  50 words.

Comment: @Anish you can use `-o` to get only matched element..see edit

Comment: @Anish sorry..i had missed the extended flag previously.The new update will work as expected..The `-E` flag would  help identify the `{}` as valid regex chars

Answer (score 1):

awk to the rescue

```
awk -v word="your word here" '{
     for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if(match($i,word)) 
         {m=i; break}
     } 
     m {
       for(i=m-3;i<=m+3;i++) 
          if(i>0 && i<=NF) print $i; 
       exit
     }'
```

will print 3 words before and after the first match if there is one.  The context of this span is a line.  If you want to expand to full paragraph add `-vRS=`